# How to apply row-wise data frame operation in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the data frame blood2 (49x3) to which I wish to apply the following row-operation.

```
cblood2[1,] <- ((blood2[1,]*mcabc)*100)/(sum(blood2[1,]*mcabc))
```

where, mcabc is a 1x3 row-vector.

I want to do the above operation on every row in blood2 (49 row-wise operations) and store the results in cblood2. But I do not want to write out each of the row-operations in my **R** code. Is there a way to do this with **tidyverse** or similar R packages?

I tried the following code but the results are different from what I expect.

```
cblood2[1:49,] <- ((blood2[1:49,]*mcabc)*100)/(sum(blood2[1:49,]*mcabc))
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` for loop over the rows and apply the function

```
out1 <- t(apply(blood2, 1, function(x) x * mcabc * 100/(sum(x * mcabc))))
```

---

Or another option with vectorized functions (`rowSums`)

```
mcabc2 <- c(mcabc)[col(blood2)]
out2 <- ((blood2 * mcabc2) * 100)/(rowSums(blood2 *mcabc2))
```

-checking the outputs

```
> identical(out1, out2)
[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
blood2 <- matrix(rnorm(49 * 3), nrow = 49, ncol = 3)
mcabc <- matrix(1:3, ncol = 3)
```